# How Would a Modern Military Use a Templar Soldier?

Tags: science-fiction, military

The military has recruited a new asset, a mutant named Templar. Templar's skin is tough enough to make him immune to small arms fire, he's three times as strong as a regular human being, he has twice the health and stamina of a human being, he can regrow lost appendages (takes up to three months and much more food than he eats normally) and he has inhuman speed, agility, and reflexes (twice that of a regular human being). He is intelligent, rational, very disciplined (as evidenced by Resist Reaper below), and has a good sense of initiative.
On top of all that, he has the following supernatural abilities:

1. Shield of Faith-Passive: Protects Templar from poison, drugs, and brainwashing. He can be manipulated, but he's naturally very resistant to manipulation (strong sense of self, very little insecurity).
2. Soul Sword-Active: Forms a sword of 'hard light', the damage of which is determined by his attack skill (training) and strength (physical capacity to bear loads), but ignores the defenses of the target, like body armor or a Kevlar vest.
3. Soul Shot-Active: Fires a projectile of  'hard light', the damage of which is determined by his attack skill (training) and strength (physical capacity to bear loads), but ignores the defenses of the target.
4. Healing Light-Templar holds a reservoir of healing energy that he can use on himself or a living thing (animal, plant, maybe even fungi but why would he heal a mushroom?). Assume he can do things like restoring lost limbs, restart hearts, mend broken bones, and the like twelve times per day.
5. Resist Reaper-Passive: When this skill activates (which is at the point of death), Crusader acts as if at full health and physical capacity for the duration, five minutes He also ignores all HP loss, status effects, and so on. Afterwards, Templar is rendered unconscious, falling into a coma-like state.
6. Azure Avenger-Active/Passive: Once activated, all enemies within range (12x12 feet) receive damage equal to all damage they inflicted upon Templar and/or his teammates combined (only within the last round). If Templar is reduced to 0 HP, this will kick in and inflict the same damage Templar was dealt upon the offender, or offender(s). Templar can only do this once every five days, unless of course it's activated naturally.

So, how would the military employ a soldier like Templar?

Please note: the military would love to recruit more mutants like Templar, but right now he's the only one.

Comment: Isn't your Templar just a run-of-the-mill common-or-garden candidate for special forces, provided he has the required level of discipline, intelligence and initiative (which you seem to consider immaterial in a soldier...). Big fast strong men are not actually good soldiers if they are also dumb, insubordinate and undecided.

Comment: Is it one of a kind superhuman, or in this worlds there are many other superhumans?

Comment: "Guys, the Lieutenant says that base has some some kind of super-soldier that the SF guys are hunting, so change of plan. We're not going to attack it. We're going to stay here, several miles away, while the artillery hammers it flat today, and then the Air Force is going to drop a non-persistent nerve agent tonight. Our job is to provide security for the assembly area here for the next 18 hours. Break out the .50 cal machine guns, the RPGs, and the night-vision goggles...just in case.

Comment: Sorry AlexP, I forgot to add mental traits. Templar is very disciplined, definitely intelligent, and has very good initiative.

Comment: "twice the health"  yeah m8 real life dont work like that

Comment: Topcode, "twice the health" means he has twice the vital force of a regular human being, which means he's twice as energetic with twice the stamina and heals twice as fast.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a good public relations candidate.

Just a bit of clarification, being a one man wrecking ball is good, but is he a team-player so to speak?

Realistically (granted you don't have a reality-check tag but could still be an option), a singular soldier with the capabilities you describe above would be in a [DARPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DARPA) blacksite or whatever equivalent your government has. They'd be running him through every conceivable test possible in order to figure out his abilities, specifically the ability to produce "hard light" (huge applications for that). They might let him out for "operational field testing" every once in a while, but he'd be well guarded.

Barring you wanting him squirreled away in a lab in your story though, I don't think any standing military would have much dire combat use for him. He's far too flashy for the special forces units and would never be sent on any sensitive missions. Even without any official news, people would follow him like a celebrity tabloid star, just because he's different. And, despite what one might think from watching the SEAL's over the past few years, the SF community really does prefer it when nobody knows about where they've been and what they've done.

That said, he's also too valuable to stick in an infantry platoon and call it a day. And so, we're back to something to do with public relations. "Hearts and minds" and all that jazz. KerrAvon2055's bodyguard idea would be one great way to do that. Also, if you don't mind ostracizing him from the regular troops, he could be the one they send in the building after high value targets once they've secured the perimeter.

If you're wondering "why would the troops dislike that?" Just imagine cornering some HVT (could be a terrorist, general, politico, whatever) and then having to wait for an untold period of time, probably while under fire, for the highly publicized "special" team to come raid the building for you, cause PR reasons.

Answer (score 1):

**Bodyguard**

Big assumption - this person can be trained to restrain himself and pretty much never use abilities 2, 3 and 6 (which are only on a par with conventional weaponry available to a military anyway) except in clearly defined circumstances.

If this assumption is correct, abilities 1 and 5 combined with the extraordinary reflexes let this person act as a bodyguard, interposing their body to shield their principal from many forms of attack.  If an attack slips through then ability 4 lets them revive their principal.

Given the nature of the modern battlefield, the person's extraordinary abilities would be *tactically* useful but not decisive. Keeping the most valuable strategist / politician / scientist alive in the face of enemy threats is *strategically* decisive.

Comment: Great ideas here, but as you can see above, Templar is already very disciplined.